# WP7: Where is SQLite db file Stored/Located?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

I am using sqlite in my app, i want to edit some data in my database,for that i want to open it using any sqlite administration tool. but i dont know where the file is located.

i am workring in windows phone 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the database that is stored in your emulator then you can use the "Isolated Storage Explorer".

Just follow the instructions on the link below and it will show you how to retrieve/save the database from/to your emulator

[Isolated Storage Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi I have a doubt, what ever the db may be, sql lite or something else, In windows phone the files will save in isolated storage only, right? or if the files save in some other place where it would be.

Answer (score 0):

As ry8806 said. it worked for me 
i did the following ;

get my app Product id from WMAppManifest.xml file

then open "Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool" in command line and

typed : ISETool.exe ts xd (Product GUID) (desktop-path)

I get all the files stored in isolated stroge.